# How to load jquery in twig file

Tags: 8, javascript

I need to run a jQuery file in a twig file in order to bind aqua lift segments.  but jQuery is not loaded yet .  How can I load jQuery at this point without loading it twice?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think your question is that you want to put inline javascript in twig templates, but it does not work, because jquery is not loaded yet?

You can override the default that the libraries are loaded in the footer and put jquery and any of your own js in the header:

mytheme.libraries.yml:

```
mylibrary:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    js/myjavascript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

mytheme.info.yml:

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/mylibrary
```

The important part is `header: true`.

If you make a dependency on `core/jquery` for the header, jquery is not loaded a second time in the footer, even if there are multiple dependencies for `core/jquery` by other libraries.

Now you can put your jquery dependend js code in the header (in this example in myjavascript.js) or put inline js in twig templates.

Answer (score 3):

```
{{ attach_library('core/jquery') }}
```